# when i activate my WordPress plugin cannot see customizer options or preview

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, themes, theme-customizer

I created a WordPress plugin but when i activate it my customizer and its preview stop working. I have attached a screenshot below.

I have tried to increase my memory to 8000M but it wasn't useful.

Below is the screenshot of what i see in customizer
[image: Customizer view]
Update:
Thanks to @JacobPeattie i was able to find that there is something wrong with the scriptStyle(). Please let me know if you see any error in the code.

```
function scriptStyle() {

    // all scripts
    wp_register_script('jquery_js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_js');
    wp_register_script('jquery_datatables_js', '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_datatables_js');
    wp_register_script('popper_js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('popper_js');
    wp_register_script('sub_bootstrap_js', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('sub_bootstrap_js');

    // all styles
    wp_register_style('jquery_datatables_css', '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery_datatables_css');
    wp_register_script('dataTableInitilize', plugins_url('js/dataTableInitilize.js', __FILE__, '', true));
    wp_enqueue_script('dataTableInitilize');

    wp_register_style('sub_bootstrap_css', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('sub_bootstrap_css');

    wp_register_style('gb-subcriber', plugins_url('css/gb-subcriber.css', __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('gb-subcriber');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'scriptStyle');
```

Update 2:
The issue is coming when i load jquery.min.js

the console is showing 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouse' of undefined"
and many other property but if I remove the jquery_js my jquery doesn't work.

Comment: It could be anything. There’s not enough information in your question. You likely have a coding error somewhere. I can only suggest removing bits of code until it works, at which point you’ll know the culprit.

Comment: ok i will try that. Meanwhile what additional information i can add?

Comment: Thank you @JacobPeattie

Comment: @PratikPurohit Welcome. Please check your browser console and attach any possible errors. It is helpful to find the source of the problem.

Comment: have updated the issue do you know anyways to resolve the conflict.